# How to distribute column widths efficiently based in the width of child elements?

Tags: html, css

I've been given a design to create in HTML/CSS that I think may be impossible, but I want to be absolutely sure before I admit defeat and go with a compromise.

A number of items containing variable length text are arranged into sets of two such that they form columns where the columns are distributed across the available width exactly, but ensuring each column is **no wider** than its widest item. Thereby it uses horizontal space as efficiently as possible while still ensuring items align perfectly as a grid. Consider this example -

```
[-a--] [-cccccc-] [-eee-] [-g---]
[-bb-] [-dddd---] [-ff--] [-hhh-]
```

Perhaps this looks tabular, but consider that the items must also wrap when the container shrinks, and still the columns maintain their magical alignment -

```
[-a---] [-cccccc-] 
[-bb--] [-dddd---] 
[-eee-] [-g------]
[-ff--] [-hhh----]
```

I can't work out how to resolve the recursive dependency of widths. That is that the width of each "column" is defined by the longest item in that column, but the total available width is known and must be an exact sum of the columns widths.

I'm happy to use a CSS3 only solution, falling back to a fixed item width solution for older browsers, but I am completely stumped as to what CSS properties can achieve this magic.

Just to provide some kind of starting point, here's a Codepen using CSS3 columns: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kiGgp

It's no good as the columns are distributed evenly, and I'm wondering if there's a way to distribute them optimally instead.

Comment: I'm thinking you're going to have to use some JavaScript magic for this.

Comment: @powerbuoy last resort, but I suspect you're right

Comment: I'd go with JavaScript, too. It's going to be far easier to make it dynamic. jQuery would be even better.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can Apply a pure CSS solution. I will write a Fiddle when I can (little busy right now) and hopefully come back with a working solution. don't lose hope yet.

Comment: what about Browser Compatibility?

Comment: Do you need to fix the wrapper width? If not, just give it a `.wrap { display: table; }` and the pairs, `.pair { display: table-cell; }`.

Comment: @MelanciaUK The wrapper will have several fixed widths at different screen sizes. I think using table display mode means it can't wrap when the container shrinks, (e.g. 4 columns down to 2 columns like in my example).

Comment: I see. So you would need to change even your HTML markup.

Comment: The "items must also wrap when the container shrinks" requirement makes it impossible with only CSS, if I understand the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to achieve what you specified even after numerous tries with the FlexBox model. (BTW: this model is currently poorly supported by browsers)

But, in my efforts, I came with a decent solution, maybe you'll like it too.

[**Demo in this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/47seG/1/)

I've manage to evenly distribute the space between the elements in **each row**, while allowing element wrapping.
each element get the exact amount of space he needs, and the rest is divided as spaces **within the row**.

but, this width remain even when elements wrap. so you don't have the 'Column like' display.

this is pure CSS, and cross Browser.
*Tested on:* IE10, IE9, IE8, Chrome, FF

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="pair">
        <p>a</p>
        <p>b</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pair">
        <p>cccccccc</p>
        <p>dddddd</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pair">
        <p>ee</p>
        <p>f</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pair">
        <p>ggggggggggg</p>
        <p>hhhhhhhhh</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pair">
        <p>iiii</p>
        <p>jjjjjj</p>
    </div>
    <div class="filler"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrap
{
    background-color: #ccc;
    line-height: 0;
    text-align: justify;
}

.pair
{
    line-height: normal;
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}

.filler
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```